# Is there a proven way to calculate the entry point(first occurence) of a factor m, in the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization, lucas-numbers

I saw a comment at the [OEIS website](https://oeis.org/A001177) for the sequence of entry points of Fibonacci factors. It referenced a paper by Mark Renault in 1996, with the quote from OEIS:
http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/FibThesis.pdf

> If m has prime factorization m=p<sub>1</sub>^e<sub>1</sub> *
>   p<sub>2</sub>^e<sub>2</sub> * ... * p<sub>n</sub>^e<sub>n</sub> then
>   a<sub>m</sub>=lcm(a<sub>p<sub>1</sub>^e<sub>1</sub></sub>,
>   a<sub>p<sub>2</sub>^e<sub>2</sub></sub>, ...,
>   a<sub>p<sub>n</sub>^e<sub>n</sub></sub>).

Is this result accepted to be true?

Comment: You mean this comment: "Wall's conjecture, which has been verified for primes up to 10^14. See A060305. Primes for which this relation fails are called Wall-Sun-Sun primes."? If so: [Open problem in mathematics:
Are there any Wall–Sun–Sun primes? If yes, is there an infinite number of them?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall%E2%80%93Sun%E2%80%93Sun_prime)...

Comment: No, below that is the prime factorization comment I mentioned, under Renault 1996.  I know about Wall's conjecture, but I'm not sure if the lcm property in the paper is proven.  Usually the comments that are written are verified by various peers.  I need to find out of the lcm property is a proven assertion, or conjecture.

Comment: OK, interesting anyway, since I also don't know...